# Posts are cropped in mobile version when photos present

Tags: bug, mobile-web

When viewing any SE site on mobile version, any posts after a post that has a photo will be cropped as in this photo:

[image]

The issue in the [question above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21692193/why-not-inherit-from-listt/21706411#21706411) I think is from the image, it is not zoomed out to fit the width, so the whole post is messed up.

Mobile: Lumia 1520, Lumia 630, both on IE 11 mobile.